# Removing intersecting lines

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I'm new to Inkscape and I'd like some advice to recreate the image below. The image was created on MS paint but the quality is poor when inserted into a Latex document.

I am having problems creating the blue rings. In my approach, I make two ellipses, resize them to fit the box and then add colour. The issue is that I am unable to delete some of the intersecting lines to create the hollow 3D effect seen in the original picture.

I attach the original and my attampt on Inkscape.

Thanks in advance!
[image: Original - MS paint]

[image: Inkscape attempt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you made that shape, but anyway here's a method to avoid the problem entirely.

- Draw a filled and stroked ellipse, Copy, Paste in Place, move to one side, select both
  shapes.
- Click *Path > Difference*
- Copy, Paste in Place, reflect, move into position.

[image]